# If $\exists v$ such that $\{v,T(v),\dots,T^{n-1}(v)\}$ is linearly independent then $T$ has $n$ different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a normal linear operator.
Assume that the inner product between two vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form: 
$(u,v)=\sum _{i=1}^n u_i\cdot \overline{v_i}$

If the vector space were unitary then I know how to prove the claim, because if the vector space were unitary , given that $T$ is normal and $\{v,T(v),\dots,T^{n-1}(v)\}$ is linearly independent, then I can show that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $T$ and also that $T$ diagonalizable, so this solves the problem.

But since the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ given that $T$ is normal doesn't imply that $T$ is diagonalizable.

I need some help, please.

Comment: Why does this solve the problem in the unitary case? How do you know that the diagonal contains different elements?

Comment: Is this an exercise you have been assigned? Are there no other hypotheses?

Comment: If $V$ is a finite dimensional unitary  vector space, and $T$ is normal, there exists a basis of $V$  containing eigenvectors of $T$ and therefore $T$ is diagonalizable .

Comment: @ArnaudD. just that $T$ is normal  and the set $\left\{v,T\left(v\right),...,T^{n-1}\left(v\right)\right\}$ is linear independent

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that $T$ is normal if the space doesn't have an inner product. I think it's understood that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is endowed with its canonical inner product.

Comment: I will add that it is the standard inner product in $R^n$

Comment: @uniquesolution and If $V$ is a finite dimensional unitary  vector space, and $T$ is normal, there exists a basis of $V$  containing eigenvectors of $T$ and therefore $T$ is diagonalizable . so the minimal poylnomial of $T$ is of the form $\left(t-\lambda _1\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(t-\lambda _k\right)$ such that $\:\:k\le n$, and all the roots are different. If we assume by contradiction that  $k<n$ then we will get a contradiction that the set $\left\{v,T\left(v\right),...,T^{n-1}\left(v\right)\right\}$ is linear independent

Comment: @idan di  Why are all the roots different? Take $T$ to be the identity operator. It is normal, right?

Comment: @uniquesolution Use the fact that $\left\{v,T\left(v\right),...,T^{n-1}\left(v\right)\right\}\:$ is linear independent

Comment: @idan di - yes, but that's not what was implied by your arguments before. When you write "given that $T$ is normal I can show that the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic polynomial" you may give an impression, as it does, that this assertion is always true, but it is not. You should be a bit more precise in writing.

Comment: correct. Got fixed